# Keep global data when uwsgi reload in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

Here is the situation:

I am using **nginx**, **uwsgi**, **python3.4**, **flask** for a web service.

In the login process, I want to setup a global variable to hold the `{'token':'user_id'}` dictionary for fast user token validation.

I have tried two ways.

1. The first is using `flask.g`. But, the problem is that the `flask.g` global variable can not share data between requests.
2. The second is using app's config dictionary, but the `app.config` dictionary will changed when `uwsgi` reloaded.

Could someone tell me how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Why not use a database. In any case, persistent storage is required for permanent storage. You can use redis/mongodb or even sqlitedict!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Flask `session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#sessions) object which does exactly what you want:

> A session basically makes it possible to remember information from one
>   request to another.

Also, a `session` is basically a python dictionary where you can store info between requests.
See [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) a small example on using `session` and the `secret_key` which it requires.

If security is your primary concern you should use the [**isdangerous**](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) module which is more secure than the default **werkzeug session**.

**Update**

Another possibility is to use [**server-side sessions**](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/) to store the session data in the database. There is even an extension - **[Flask-KVSession](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/)** - which stores session data on a variety of backends.

Comment: However, default flask's sessions implementation stores all session data on the client site (in browser cookies). So, be careful storing private data in default flask sessions.

Comment: @Ostrovski, Thanks for you nice remind. it sounds a big risk using flask's sessions

Comment: @doru, another question, if the uwsgi reloaded, the session will gone, right? How could i keep the data when uwsgi reloaded?

Comment: @JohnShu It seems that `uwsgi` can be gracefully restarted: "When running with the master process mode, the uWSGI server can be gracefully restarted without closing the main sockets.

This functionality allows you patch/upgrade the uWSGI server without closing the connection with the web server and losing a single request". See [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Management.html) and [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html) more info.